# c++ combine hash functions using std::bitset

Tags: c++, hash

I recently came across a blog https://worldengineer.me/2015/02/08/combining-container-hashes-with-c14-metaprogramming-cure-for-insomnia-1729/

Where the author combines two hashes by reducing them to their std::bitset representation and concatenating the bitsets and finding the hash of the combined bitset.

Granted that probably the motive of the article was to introduce c++ 14 features, i was wondering how good this approach is compared to say, the boost hash_combine function purely on the basis of collision resistance?

**EDIT:**

By good i mean how does it fare in avoiding collisions compared to the boost libraries' hash_combine method? And performance wise is it a good option, though i don't think the above approach should take much longer than the hash_combine method.

I am not doing any serious development with this, just prodding around so just wanted to know the merit of the approach.

Comment: What is your definition of "good" here? This is otherwise a pretty broad question.

Comment: @AndyG By good i mean collision resistance, like how far apart they place far away values

Answer (score 2):

I would say that

- to hack around and discover new stuff it is fun (do it yourself with std::bitset),
- but in a serious development prefer using libraries like boost that will hasten your development and avoid errors. Moreover this library is open source and has been developed and read by hundred of professionals.